# It´s possible retrive or refresh a password by secretmanagerid in AWS, the password has been rotated by a policy every five minutes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

well that´s the question, It´s possible to retrieve or refresh a password by secretmanagerid in AWS?, the password has been rotated by a policy every five minutes. I don´t want to restart my microservice to retrieve the pass, I was looking for a solution and I found something like this:

```
<groupId>com.amazonaws.secretsmanager</groupId>

<artifactId>aws-secretsmanager-jdbc</artifactId>

<version>1.0.5</version>
```

spring:

datasource:

```
url: jdbc-secretsmanager:mysql://database-host:3306/rotate_db

username: secret/rotation

driver-class-name: com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerMySQLDriver
```

But I don't want to use the configuration in the application.yml or .properties, I want to keep these values in the parameter store as secrets, currently my code looks like this:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        AwsSecrets secrets = getSecret();
        if(Objects.nonNull(secrets)){
            log.info("Getting parameters: host: {}, port: {}, Db: {}, user: {}, pass: {}", secrets.getHost(), secrets.getPort(), secrets.getDatabase(),secrets.getUsername(), secrets.getPassword());
            DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .url("jdbc:postgresql://" + secrets.getHost() + ":" + secrets.getPort() + "/" + secrets.getDatabase())
                    .username(secrets.getUsername())
                    .password(secrets.getPassword())
                    .build();
            return new TracingDataSource(dataSource);
        }
        log.debug("Unable to get secrets");
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter tracingFilter() {
        return new AWSXRayServletFilter("back-microservice");
    }


    private AwsSecrets getSecret() {

        AWSSecretsManager client = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(amazonRegion)
                .withCredentials(dynamoDBConfig.accountAmazonAWSCredentials())
                .build();

        String secret;
        GetSecretValueRequest getSecretValueRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest()
                .withSecretId(secretmanagerId);
        GetSecretValueResult getSecretValueResult = null;

        try {
            getSecretValueResult = client.getSecretValue(getSecretValueRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Unable to get secrets values");
            throw e;
        }
        if (getSecretValueResult.getSecretString() != null) {
            secret = getSecretValueResult.getSecretString();
            return gson.fromJson(secret, AwsSecrets.class);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean about not wanting to use the `application.yml` or `.properties`? You don't need to put any secrets in those files -- that's the whole point of the secretsmanager driver....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do. The exact implementation will vary by framework/ORM, but you would need to cache the credentials, but also check if a new password is needed **every time** a new connection is acquired.

In your code, you are setting the password once statically:

```java
            DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .url("jdbc:postgresql://" + secrets.getHost() + ":" + secrets.getPort() + "/" + secrets.getDatabase())
                    .username(secrets.getUsername())
                    .password(secrets.getPassword())
                    .build();
```

The `getPassword()` function is only ever called once when you build the datasource and is reused for additional connections from that data source. Instead, you need to retrieve (from cache/secretsmanger) *every* time a connection is created.

AWS provides a [java caching client for AWS secretsmanager](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-java/) (clients for other languages are also available). You can adapt that into your data source to use that to retrieve the password for *every connection*. You can read the official guidance documentation on that here: [Rotate database credentials without restarting containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/rotate-database-credentials-without-restarting-containers.html).

In the context of Spring, that means implementing this pattern in your data source driver, which is exactly what the `com.amazonaws.secretsmanager.sql.AWSSecretsManagerMySQLDriver` class provides. Because you are rotating the secret so often, you probably want to [configure the secret cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_cache-java-ref_SecretCacheConfiguration.html) to refresh more often than the default of 1 hour or adjust your rotation frequency.

If you really need to be rotating the password that often and you're using RDS for your database, you might consider just using IAM-based authentication instead. I can't imagine why you would want to have a password that rotates so frequently, keeping in mind you are billed for secret retrieval API calls.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, and I apologize for my delay, I implement the handle request method with the SecretCache class for retrieve the new password, I put this method inside another methods for testing purposes, and all works perfectly, when I change the pass, the microservice can retrieve it  with the help from this method. But now my problem is the data source, I cant find the way for use the method "handleRequest(secretKey)" and update the pass in the data source, I tried to use it in my DataSource config bean but is useless.

Comment: About the rotation every 5 minutes is for testing proposes, the reality is that it will be every 15 days.